# Beginner's program keeps crashing

Tags: c, crash

I'm new to C and wrote a little program for generating an interest table. However, the program keeps crashing. Unfortunately, I didn't really find any matching answers and I'm out of ideas for fixing it. How do I fix the program from crashing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
float kapital;
float zins(int jahr, int prozent);


void tabelle()
{
    printf("\n    |1%    2%    3%    4%    5%    6%    7%    8%    9%    10%");
    printf("\n----+---------------------------------------------------------\n");

    int jahr,prozent;

    for(jahr=1; jahr<=10; jahr++)
    {
        printf("%3d |", jahr);
        for(prozent=1; prozent<=10; prozent++)
        {
            printf("%5d", zins(jahr, prozent));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}//tabelle()

float zins(jahr,prozent)
{
  float zinssatz = prozent/100;
  int i;
  float kapitalneu;
  float zwischenkapital=kapital;

  for(i=1;i<=jahr;i++)
  {
      kapitalneu = kapital*zinssatz;
      zwischenkapital = zwischenkapital + kapitalneu + 0.005; //+0.005 um zu     runden, um die Tabelle im Rahmen zu halten
  }
  return zwischenkapital;

}//zins(p,j)

int main()
{
    printf("Kapital :");
    scanf("%i", kapital);
    tabelle();

}//main()
```

Comment: thanks, but still strange values

Comment: thanks guys, got everything fixed like planned ♥

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted then.

Answer (score 2):

In definition of your zins() function, you should write the same types as in the forward declaration, so change `float zins(jahr, prozent)` to `float zins(int jahr, int prozent)` and it will compile. Also, in your main function, you should change `scanf("%i", kapital);` to `scanf("%f", &kapital);`, because you need to provide the scanf function with an adress, to store the input, which is float, for which you use %f. Also, it is generally a good idea not to use global variables.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, helped fixing the crash. But now the values in the table are strange, propably type problem ?

Comment: I don't speak German, so I don't know what output you expect. I suggest trying what @user3121023 advices, instead of float `zinssatz = prozent/100;` try `float zinssatz = prozent/100.0;`.